# Upgraded to windows 10 & now cant open settings

Tags: windows, powershell, settings, command-prompt

ive just spend all morning trying to figure this out
finally found an answer that worked so thought id share it.

Answer: Open setting through command promt - See below

Answer (score 0):

[image]How to open settings through command promt:

1. Search for command promt in windows start menu.
2. Click to open
3. At the end of the C:\Users line type `start ms-settings:`
4. Enter

I only needed to open settings through the command promt once & then i could open settings through all the usual methods

Best of Luck